# How to adjust height of UICollectionView to be the height of the content size of the UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I would like the UICollectionView (The red one) to shrink to the height of the content size in this case UICollectionViewCells(the yellow ones) because there is a lot of empty space. What I tried is to use:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if !__CGSizeEqualToSize(bounds.size, self.intrinsicContentSize) {
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return self.collection.contentSize
}
```

but `return self.collection.contentSize` always return (width, 0)
and for this reason it shrinks too much to value of height 30 (The value which I set in the XIB file for the height, although I have constaint >= 30).

[image]

Comment: You've to take height constraint outlet of ColletionView and adjust height like this `heightConstraint.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height`

Comment: Are You using custom layout or the provided by Apple - UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Comment: I am using the default one UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: Than You should use collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize, see @hasan83's answer. It is a possibility for You.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

**I would suggest the following:**

> 1. Add a height constraint to your collection view.
> 2. Set its priority to 999.
> 3. Set its constant to any value that makes it reasonably visible on the storyboard.
> 4. Change the bottom equal constraint of the collection view to greater or equal.
> 5. Connect the height constraint to an outlet.
> 6. Every time you reload the data on the collection view do the following:

*You may also want to consider the Inset of the collection view by adding it to the content size.*

**Code Sample:**

```
CGFloat height = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
heightConstraint.constant = height
self.view.setNeedsLayout() Or self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

**Explanation: Extra, You don't have to read if you understand it. obviously!!**

The UI will try to reflect all the constraints no matter what are their priorities. Since there is a height constraint with lower priority of **(999)**, and a bottom constraint of type greater or equal. whenever, the height constraint constant is set to a value less than the parent view height the collection view will be equal to the given height, achieving both constraints.

But, when the height constraint constant set to a value more than the parent view height both constraints can't be achieved. Therefore, only the constraint with the higher priority will be achieved which is the greater or equal bottom constraint.

The following is just a guess from an experience. So, it achieves one constrant. But, it also tries to make the **error** in the resulted UI for the other un-achieved lower priority constraint **as lowest as possible**. Therefore, the collection view height will be equal to the parent view size.

Comment: Mine expands to some extent but not perfect. It misses about 3 4 lines of the label. Any idea? Here is how it looks: https://ibb.co/jeO9Rv
https://ibb.co/iV8b6v

Comment: @Nil Do you have a header or footer on your collection view? the height of the footer and the header must be added.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked. The height constraint was set to proportional height that's why setting just only the constant was making some difference not much.

Comment: While we are talking, do you have any idea how to pin a cell to the top? In my horizontal collectionview some cells are not pinned to the top. Just randomly floating in middle. Here: https://ibb.co/fHbSwv

Comment: @hasan83 I am getting some extra height of collection view by this way, any suggestion ?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya hmm, maybe its something with the collection view headers and footers? did you add any view in the collection view on the storyboard?

Comment: or maybe its with point 4. Change the bottom equal constraint of the collection view to greater or equal. Greater or equal which means the height of the collectionview should always be less or equal to the height of its parent view

Comment: @hasan83 No i have not added any view in collection view or no any header and footers are there. In my design i have just scroll view and collection view is inside content view of scrollview and 2 other views. All have fix height and collection view has fix height outlet. So when i reloading collection view, i am just getting hight based on it's content and assigning to its height constant. But unfortunately getting some extra height.

Comment: what I proposed in my answer doesn't work as it is on a scrollview. thats the problem. you got the idea on how you can do that on a view. so, think the same to figure out a solution for your situation

Comment: Like others in the comments I was getting some extra height when using this method. To fix this I simply did a `.reloadData()` and then changed the constant of the height constraint within a collection view `performBatchUpdates`.

Comment: Are you able to use this programmatically as well, or just with storyboards?

Comment: You can add the constraints programmatically. if that what you mean @ArielSD
we already have some Code involved even with the storyboard version!

Comment: @hasan The collectionView I'm using is nested in a stackView in a tableViewCell - where should I call `setNeedsLayout`?

Comment: If you find the contentsize returned is higher than actual, set the initial height constant to something large like 1000.

Comment: I use RxSwift to detect when the height of the collection view changes (like when I configure it by calling reloadData after updating the relevant data). In the closure that is invoked by the observer, I do the update of the height constraint and call layoutIfNeeded - also on the superviews. The code for the observer is: collectionView.rx.observe(CGSize.self , "contentSize").subscribe(onNext: { (size) in <your code here>}

Comment: if you're using **UIScrollView** as parent of the collection view, need to do slight change. Try, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70285535/10505343

Answer (score 36):

In Swift 5 and Xcode 10.2.1

My CollectionView name is **myCollectionView**

1. Fix height for your CollectionView
2. Create Outlet for your CollectionViewHeight

   ```
   IBOutlet weak var myCollectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
   ```
3. Use below code

   ```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       let height = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
       myCollectionViewHeight.constant = height
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   }
   ```

Dynamic width for cell based on text content...

[Dynamic cell width of UICollectionView depending on label width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134986/dynamic-cell-width-of-uicollectionview-depending-on-label-width/68907152#68907152)

Comment: what does it myCollectionView in your code.Where you declared

Comment: @ Karthi Rasu, myCollectionView is your collection view height constraint. If you are using storyboard fix height of collectionView.

Comment: Perfect solution !!

Comment: Dynamic width for cell... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134986/dynamic-cell-width-of-uicollectionview-depending-on-label-width/68907152#68907152

Answer (score 23):

1) Set Fix Height of your CollectionView.

2) Create Outlet of this CollectionView Height Constant.
   Like :

> IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constHeight;

3) Add below method in your .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGFloat height = collectionMenu.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;
    constHeight.constant = height;
}
```

Comment: This worked using `Swift 5` and `Xcode 10.2.1`. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

This seemed like the simplest solution for me.

```
class SelfSizingCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }
}
```

You may not need to override `reloadData`

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me on iOS 14. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Best one so far!

Answer (score 20):

I ended up, by subclassing the `UICollectionView` and overriding some methods as follows.

- Returning `self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize` for `intrinsicContentSize` makes sure, to always have the correct size
- Then just call it whenever it might change (like on `reloadData`)

Code:

```
override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()
    self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
}
```

**But be aware, that you lose "cell re-using", if you display large sets of data, eventhough they don't fit on the screen.**

Comment: This works to make the `UICollectionView` initially the size of its content, but if the content changes ie: insert or delete rows, it doesn't resize. And if I call reload data the collection view stutters as it resizes. Any way to stop this stuttering?

Comment: Did you try calling `self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` without calling `reloadData()`? Maybe this could work.

Comment: By far the most beautiful solution - at least for my use case. Thank you. It solves the problem of timing, layout needs all other constraints and views to be sized to determine content size - this one just works.

Comment: Actually - I had to constrain the intrinsic size to be at least 1 - never 0 - for this to correctly work. Otherwise there were small errors in the calculation, cutting off the bottom of the view by a few pixels.

Comment: Why does this mean you lose cell re-use? Not clear on what is causing that using this method.

Comment: @AnthonyMDev Because using this approach, you're resizing the collection view to fit all items at the same time, so all items are loading any time.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense. I was thinking it was breaking the actual dequeue logic, but it's just a fact of the collection view displaying all the cells at all times. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @cabyambo Were you able to find the solution for it?

Comment: using NSCompositionalLayout, I had to initialize intrinsicContentSize first by a dummy non zero CGSize to enable the layout to first draw its content. specifically: 'self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize == .zero ? CGSize(width: 100, height: 200) : self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize'

Answer (score 9):

You have to set height constraint as equal to content size

```
HeightConstraint.constant = collection.contentSize.height
```

Answer (score 8):

Took the solution by d4Rk which is great, except in my case it would keep cutting off the bottom of my collection view (too short). I figured out this was because intrinsic content size was sometimes 0 and this would throw off the calculations. IDK. All I know is this fixed it.

```
import UIKit

class SelfSizedCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let s = self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
        return CGSize(width: max(s.width, 1), height: max(s.height,1))
    }

}
```

Comment: that is very weird I don't know why need to setup first value 1 to start calculate the final value.

Answer (score 7):

1. Subclass UICollectionView as follows
2. Delete height constraint if any
3. Turn on Intrinsic Size

---

```
class ContentSizedCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override func reloadData() { // optional
        super.reloadData()

        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you set the height constraint of the collection view. Just observe the `contentSize` change in the viewDidLoad and update the constraint.

```
        self.contentSizeObservation = collectionView.observe(\.contentSize, options: [.initial, .new]) { [weak self] collectionView, change in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            guard self.collectionView.contentSize != .zero else { return }
            self.collectionViewHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a multi-line, multi-selection `UICollectionView` subclass where the cells are of fixed height and left-aligned flowing from left to right. It's embedded in a vertical stack view that's inside a vertical scroll view. See the UI component below the label "Property Types".

[image]

In order for the collection view to fit the height of its `contentSize`, here's what I had to do (note that this is all within the `UICollectionView` subclass):

1. Give the collection view a non-zero minimum height constraint of priority `999`. Auto-sizing the collection view to its content height simply won't work with zero height.

   ```
   let minimumHeight = heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 1)
   minimumHeight.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)
   minimumHeight.isActive = true
   ```
2. Set the collection view's content hugging priority to `.required` for the vertical axis.

   ```
   setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
   ```
3. Calling `reloadData()` is followed by the following calls:

   ```
   invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
   setNeedsLayout()
   layoutIfNeeded()
   ```

   For example, I have a `setItems()` function in my subclass:

   ```
   func setItems(_ items: [Item]) {
     self.items = items
     selectedIndices = []
     reloadData()
     invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
     setNeedsLayout()
     layoutIfNeeded()
   }
   ```
4. Override `contentSize` and `intrinsicContentSize` as follows:

   ```
   override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
     return contentSize
   }

   override var contentSize: CGSize {
     didSet {
       invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
       setNeedsLayout()
       layoutIfNeeded()
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: can u share the full code ?

Answer (score 3):

Do following.

1. first set height constrain for `UICollectionView`
2. here  `calendarBaseViewHeight` is `UICollectionView` height Variable
3. call the function after reload the collection view

   ```
   func resizeCollectionViewSize(){  
          calendarBaseViewHeight.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height      
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

On your `UICollectionView` set your constraints such as `Trailing`, `Leading`, and `Bottom`:

[image: UICollectionView constraints]

If you look at my height constraint in more detail, as it is purely for storyboard look so I don't get errors, I have it to `Remove at build time`. The real height constraint is set in my code down below.

[image: UICollectionView height constraint]

My code for `DrawerCollectionView`, which is set as the collection view `Custom Class`:

[image: UICollectionView custom class]

```
import UIKit

class DrawerCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentSize.height).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried, but that didn't work for me. The other subclassing solution by d4Rk worked with minor modifications

Answer (score 1):

**Adjusting height of UICollectionView to the height of it's content size**

SWIFT 5

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // it's important to declare layout as separate constant due to late update in viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    private let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    private lazy var collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        setupCollectionView()
        setupCollectionViewConstraints()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
        updateFlowLayout()
    }

    private func setupCollectionView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "UICollectionViewCell")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    private func setupCollectionViewConstraints() {
        // your collectionView constraints setup
    }

    private func updateFlowLayout() {
        let height = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height)
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = .zero
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = .zero
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {...}
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all calculate number of cells than multiply it with height of cell and then return height in this method

```
   collectionView.frame = CGRectMake (x,y,w,collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height); //objective c
   collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height) // swift
```

Comment: This method returns the size for a specific cell at index path, if You set the height to noOfCell*heightOfCell this will set the height of all the cells.

Comment: @Georgi Boyadzhiev, that's true.

Comment: `This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question.` Man, this question wouldn't be asked if it was simple to calculate all the inner items heights.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a UICollectionView in UITableView cell. For me, the following solution worked.

In parent view of collection view, I updated the height constraint in `layoutSubviews` method like this

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    heightConstraint.constant = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
}
```

and then in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`, just before returning the cell, call this

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution worked for me when `CollectionView` is inside `TableView` custom cell is to

1. Subclass from `ContentSizedCollectionView`:

```
final class ContentSizedCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize{
            didSet {
                if oldValue.height != self.contentSize.height {
                    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
                }
            }
        }

        override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric,
                          height: contentSize.height)
        }
}
```

```
private let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 17, bottom: 20, right: 17)
        
        let collectionView = ContentSizedCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout).prepareForAutoLayout()
        
        return collectionView
    }()
```

2. In `UITableViewDelegate` for `TableView` cell (cellForRowAt):

```
if let reusableCell = cell as? YourTableViewCell {
            reusableCell.frame = tableView.bounds
            reusableCell.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

3. Remove height constraints of `UICollectionView` if any.

This article helped me a lot: https://medium.com/@ar.sarris/self-sizing-collectionview-inside-a-tableview-f1fd4f42c44d

Answer (score -1):

work for me

```
    let heightRes = resCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
    foodHeightConstrant.constant = height.advanced(by: 1 )

    foodCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
    foodCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: how many redraws will it take if content size is enough big?

Answer (score -1):

Get the height of the cell. Something like this

```
let cellHeight = cell.frame.height
```

Get the origin of the collection view

```
let cvOrigin = collectionView.frame.origin
```

Get the width of the collection view

```
let cvWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
```

Set the frame of the content view

```
collection.frame = CGRect(x: cvOrigin.x, y: cvOrigin.y, width: cvWidth, height: cellHeight )
```