# CollectionView Height Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How can I increase my cell height. Also I am increasing cell height from storyboard but it's not working.
Note: (Only I want to increase What's New Cells Height)

[image]

Code:-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if let flowLayout = collectionview.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let horizontalSpacing = flowLayout.scrollDirection == .vertical ? flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing : flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing
        let cellWidth = (view.frame.width - max(0, numberOfCellsPerRow - 1)*horizontalSpacing)/numberOfCellsPerRow

        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
    }


    return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width - 8) / 3.0 , height: (self.view.frame.width - 8) / 3.0)
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have used `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` this along with the class name.

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42438709/9333764)

Comment: is this one collection view, or three collection views?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ in this page these has three collectionViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeForItemAt` is called for every item in your collection. This code:

```
if let flowLayout = collectionview.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let horizontalSpacing = flowLayout.scrollDirection == .vertical ? flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing : flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing
    let cellWidth = (view.frame.width - max(0, numberOfCellsPerRow - 1)*horizontalSpacing)/numberOfCellsPerRow

    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
}
```

Looks like it belongs to `viewDidLoad`, or somewhere else where it would be called just once. Moreover, if I am not mistaken, setting `flowLayout.itemSize` is used when all the items have the same size - thus it cannot not be combined with `sizeForItemAt` implementation (in other words, I would remove it altogether.

This is what gets applied in the end:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width - 8) / 3.0 , height: (self.view.frame.width - 8) / 3.0)
}
```

So to change the height of the cells in the given `collectionView` just change the height in the returned `CGSize`, e.g., to `collectionView.frame.height` to fit the `collectionView`'s height:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width - 8) / 3.0 , height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```