# How can I dynamically set multiple buttons having different length of string according to screen's width?

Tags: ios, swift, button, layout

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [uimovement.com](https://uimovement.com/media/resource_image/gif_thumb_thumbnail_wT9ijPg.jpg))</sub>

I want to implement layout like the above(auto line break when screen's width is not enough to accommodate buttons' widths).
But I can't come up with any idea about how to make that image like layout. I just can implement statically, not dynamically.

In Android, there is a layout that can implement the above.
But I don't know what can help me implement the above image in swift.
Please help me.

---

Following @Matthew Mitchell 's suggestion.
I implemented it like below.

My ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var hobbyArray = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
//        self.collectionView!.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        hobbyArray.append("test1")
        hobbyArray.append("test2")
        hobbyArray.append("test3")
        hobbyArray.append("test4")
        hobbyArray.append("test5")
        hobbyArray.append("test5")
        hobbyArray.append("test5123123")
        
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hobbyArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        
        cell.title.text = self.hobbyArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let text = self.hobbyArray[indexPath.row]
        let cellWidth = text.size(withAttributes:[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:17)]).width + 25
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 35.0)
    }
}
```

Other codes are implemented exactly equal to @Matthew Mitchell's codes.
However, still I can't get what I wanted to implement.

[image]

I failed to make what I had wanted.

Comment: `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` might help.

Comment: Weird that not all the cells are showing, have to set up your UICollectionView constraints correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this efficiently you need to have a `UICollectionView` with a custom `FlowLayout`. I am going to do a `storyboard` example. This is quite complicated so I will try my best. All the code will be below the steps.

Step 1: Create a swift file named CollectionViewFlowLayout and use UICollectionViewLayout code in the newly created class.

Step 2: Add a `UICollectionView` to your `ViewController`

Step 3: Link new UICollectionView layout with the CollectionViewFlowLayout class

[image: Picture 1]

Step 4: Create a UICollectionViewCell inside the UICollectionView, add a label to that cell and constrain it to left and right in the cell and center it vertically. In the attributes inspector of the cell give it a reusable identifier ("cell" for this example)

[image: UICollectionViewCell]

Step 6: Create a swift file named collectionViewCell and use UICollectionViewCell class that links to your collectionViewCell (same way you linked your flowlayout in step 3).

Step 7: Add ViewController code to your ViewController Class. This code allows you to add cells to your collection view. The sizeForItemAt function will allow you to resize the cells according to the width of the string that you put inside each cell.

Code:

ViewController:

```
    import UIKit


        class viewController: UIViewController {

            //Outlets
            @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                collectionView.delegate = self
                collectionView.dataSource = self
            }
        }

        extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return YOUR_ITEM_COUNT
            }

            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

                self.title.text = YOUR_ITEMS_LIST[indexPath.row]
                return cell
            }

            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

            let text = YOUR_ITEMS_LIST[indexPath.row]
            let cellWidth = text!.size(withAttributes:[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:17)]).width + 25
            return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 35.0)
        }
    }
```

UICollectionViewCell:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
}
```

UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var tempCellAttributesArray = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    let leftEdgeInset: CGFloat = 0

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let cellAttributesArray = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        //Oth position cellAttr is InConvience Emoji Cell, from 1st onwards info cells are there, thats why we start count from 2nd position.
        if(cellAttributesArray != nil && cellAttributesArray!.count > 1) {
            for i in 1..<(cellAttributesArray!.count) {
                let prevLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = cellAttributesArray![i - 1]
                let currentLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = cellAttributesArray![i]
                let maximumSpacing: CGFloat = 8
                let prevCellMaxX: CGFloat = prevLayoutAttributes.frame.maxX
                //UIEdgeInset 30 from left
                let collectionViewSectionWidth = self.collectionViewContentSize.width - leftEdgeInset
                let currentCellExpectedMaxX = prevCellMaxX + maximumSpacing + (currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width )
                if currentCellExpectedMaxX < collectionViewSectionWidth {
                    var frame: CGRect? = currentLayoutAttributes.frame
                    frame?.origin.x = prevCellMaxX + maximumSpacing
                    frame?.origin.y = prevLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.y
                    currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame ?? CGRect.zero
                } else {
                    // self.shiftCellsToCenter()
                    currentLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x = leftEdgeInset
                    //To Avoid InConvience Emoji Cell
                    if (prevLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x != 0) {
                        currentLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.y = prevLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.y + prevLayoutAttributes.frame.size.height + 08
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return cellAttributesArray
    }

    func shiftCellsToCenter() {
        if (tempCellAttributesArray.count == 0) {return}
        let lastCellLayoutAttributes = self.tempCellAttributesArray[self.tempCellAttributesArray.count-1]
        let lastCellMaxX: CGFloat = lastCellLayoutAttributes.frame.maxX
        let collectionViewSectionWidth = self.collectionViewContentSize.width - leftEdgeInset
        let xAxisDifference = collectionViewSectionWidth - lastCellMaxX
        if xAxisDifference > 0 {
            for each in self.tempCellAttributesArray{
                each.frame.origin.x += xAxisDifference/2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run into problems let me know

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfertly. I missed some basic points.

Comment: Ah great! Glad I could help! Had a hard time doing this myself for the first time, not so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout or use a fully custom solution with UIView as root and different UIScrollViews with some custom content as lines (cells) here. 
I have an example, but it's too huge to post here. Write me if you are inserting in.

Comment: Please give me url link to your example.

Comment: https://github.com/volmalakhov/TransactionFilterSample here you are. It was build as independent as possible, but unfortunately there are some logic links to the main project, I hope it would help. also it uses SnapKit for UI. @KazakaNelson

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i found a shortest and super easy solution to make the height dynamic by subclassing `UICollectionView` and assign it to the CollectionView.
Here's the code:

```
class DynamicHeightCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    }
}
```

I am attaching reference link to that solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297382/9738186