# Dynamically change constraint of a view

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I'm trying to replicate an app design I saw on Dribbble (just for learning) and I have a question about dynamically changing a view's constraint. 
I have a collectionView, which might now contain cells at all.

Below that collectionView I have a view (UILabel), I want to change the UILabel topAnchor constraint, so if I have only one cell in the collectionView the UILabel will be displayed higher on screen. How can I do that? I have my View and ViewController separated, so when I set the constraints on the View file, there are no cells at all.

for example, In this state, I want the "To do list" label to be closer to the one cell I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YVZb.jpg

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/56802898/5523205

Comment: That label can be footer of the `collection` or `tableView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have automatic dimension for `UICollectionView`, they only affect the `UICollectionViewCell` height. If you want to set the collection view height dynamically, I think the best way is to set the collection view height constraint equal to its content size after the collection view done loading. I mean something like,

```
collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
```

then set your label at the bottom of your collectionView and set the maximum `desired height` `collectionViewHeightConstraint` can have

also this tutorial may help you [Self sizing table view](https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/swift-4-recipe-self-sizing-table-view-2635ac3df8ab)

write this code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let height = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
    myCollectionViewHeight.constant = height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: It should be `collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height`

Comment: Thanks, where should I write it ? I tried to write it inside a function that gets called in the ViewDidLoad, I guess it won't work because the collectionView didn't finish loading when I get to the ViewDidLoad, but how can I know when it did finish loading?

Comment: override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let height = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
    myCollectionViewHeight.constant = height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

Comment: Thank you! DidLayoutSubViews didn't work for some reason, but viewDidAppear did.