# iOS Autolayout UIControl subclass automatically resize to fit UICollectionView subview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, constraints

I have a subclass of `UIControl` which contains (and controls) a `UICollectionView`. I'm trying to get it to auto-resize to fit the collectionView, but haven't had any success yet.

The collection view is set up in a common init method of the `UIControl` subclass as follows:

```swift
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)

collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
addSubview(collectionView)
```

If anyone could help with this, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using layout constraints?

Comment: @SahilKapoor I have tried, but as of yet, I've been unsuccessful. I wasn't quite sure what I was doing wrong, so I removed them from the code above in the hopes that someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new custom Method in UIControl subclass and move init code in this method.Than in collectionview willdisplay delegate method called that custom method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42438709/10028548). Subclassing the `UICollectionView` [like so](https://paste.mod.gg/opajefezac.cs) fixed it.