# How to dynamically change the height of UICollectionView to adapt to content size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have two collection views in the same view and I would like to reduce the height of them, so that they adapt to the content size. However, the height should only reduce and never increase more than the initial value set in the storyboard. How can I accomplish this?

So far I have tried changing the collectionView height from the height costraint outlet everytime I would add new data but I don't get the right result.
I tried changing it with this code:

```
self.deadlineCollectionViewHeight.constant = deadlinesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
```

[image: expected behaviour]
[image: Wrong result]

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42438709/14437411

Comment: Have you tried adding self.view.layoutIfNeeded() just above self.deadlineCollectionViewHeight.constant = deadlinesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At what point are you trying to read the `collectionViewContentSize` value?

If you are doing that right after a `reloadData()` call - that might not give you accurate results because these calls are deferred to be executed at some point on main thread. The content size won't change immediately after doing the `reloadData()` call.

Try following :

1. Declare a variable inside the class like this.

```swift
private var contentSizeObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

2. Start observing contentSize changes.

```swift
contentSizeObservation = deadlinesCollectionView.observe(\.contentSize, options: .new, changeHandler: { [weak self] (cv, _) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.deadlineCollectionViewHeight.constant = cv.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
})
```

3. Do NOT Forget to clean this up in `deinit` call -

```swift
deinit {
    contentSizeObservation?.invalidate()
}
```

This approach will make sure that your collectionView is always as big in height as it's content.

Comment: Wau, thank you very very much. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Your solution works as long as I don't change the collectionview datasource. If I have 0 deadlines and I a new one, deadlines content size is still 0 and the cell doesn't display. I posted another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587680/wrong-result-when-dynamically-changing-the-height-of-the-collectionview-to-adapt

Answer (score 0):

Add height constraint outlet then set it as you wish.

```
collectionViewheightConstraint.constant = modifierCollectionView.contentSize.height + 4
```