# Wrong result when dynamically changing the height of the CollectionView to adapt to content size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my `DetailViewController`, I have two `collectionViews` and I am trying to change their height dynamically. I can successfully achieve this by changing the two heigh constraints `IBOutlets` with observers in `DetailViewController`. However, it does not work if, from `DetailViewController` I push another ViewController and then I go back.

This is the code in "DetailViewController"

```
@IBOutlet weak var deadlineCollectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var tasksCollectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

private var CVcontentSizeObservation: [NSKeyValueObservation]?

private var initialCollectionViewsHeight: InitialCollectionViewsHeight?

override func viewDidLoad() {

     super.viewDidLoad()
     initialCollectionViewsHeight = InitialCollectionViewsHeight(deadlines: 
     deadlineCollectionViewHeight.constant, tasks: tasksCollectionViewHeight.constant)
     observeCollectionView()

 }

private func observeCollectionView(){

    CVcontentSizeObservation = [

         deadlinesCollectionView.observe(\.contentSize, options: .new, changeHandler: {[weak self] (cv, _) in
        
               guard let self = self else { return }
            
               if cv.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height < self.initialCollectionViewsHeight!.deadlines{
            
                    self.deadlineCollectionViewHeight.constant = cv.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
            
                }
         }),
    
        tasksCollectionView.observe(\.contentSize, options: .new, changeHandler: {[weak self] (cv, _) in
        
             guard let self = self else { return }
            
             if cv.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height < self.initialCollectionViewsHeight!.tasks{
            
                     self.tasksCollectionViewHeight.constant = cv.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
             }
       })
   ]

}

private struct InitialCollectionViewsHeight{
    var deadlines: CGFloat
     var tasks: CGFloat
}
```

**The problem**

This works fine if from the home VC I push the `DetailViewController`, but if from there I push another VC and then go back, I get a wrong result.

The first image shows the correct behavior after the `DetailViewController` is initially pushed. However, if I press on the "Edit Button" button and a new VC is pushed, I get a wrong result after I dismiss it and pop the VC from the stack (i.e: I go back to `DetailViewController`), as seen in the second image

[image: Right result]
[image: Wrong result]

Comment: Even though I am not sure why you're experiencing this behaviour, I'd probably follow a different approach: the idea of UICollectionView is to be dynamic per se. You shouldn't need to manually change a constraint based on the content size of the collection view. Instead you should use constraints to specify the legal area where your content view can 'live in' and then it should figure how to size itself on its own.

Comment: @Petar The problem is that once I set the collectionview height costraint, the frame is than fixed and the height doesn't change. Am i worong?

Comment: Yeah  ignore what I sad - you can't do that with scrollviews because they don't have an intrinsic content size. Since you want to add 2 scroll views you should specify the height of at least one of them. What you've written makes sense and I think the problem is somewhere else - looks like the whole view is broken: notice that the info label is not in its original position as well. Care to share your code ?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are trying to make collection views to fit their height. Using constraint approach may bring some problems, due to UICollectionViewLayout behaviour.

I would recommend using this approach:

```
class AutoSizingCollectionView : UICollectionView
{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        if (!self.bounds.size.equalTo(self.intrinsicContentSize)) {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize
    {
        return self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    }
}
```

Exchange your CollectionViews with `AutoSizingCollectionView` class and they will scale their height to their content size automatically using `IntrinsicContentSize` method. It will allow you to easily pin bottom collection view to bottom of the first one.

I hope that solves root of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response, this works in certain cases(however I had to remove the height constraint from the storyboard).In fact,  When I have less than three-element, as I try to add a new cell by pressing the "Add deadline", it looks like the content size stays the same, so the collection view tries to fit three cells in the space where there two before. The content size is correctly calculated if then I pop the VC and then push it again.

Comment: When adding or removing elements, you may need to `invalidateLayout` for that case and maybe call layoutIfNeeded so everything gets recalculated. Layouts are cached otherwise and they will not recalculate the contentSize properly.


And height constraints should be all removed, otherwise autosizing won't work properly. IntrinsicContentSize only works when element has not defined height constraint.

Comment: Try have a look, I have updated the question and I still can't get the collectionview to increment the content size when a new element is added. I also get a weird behavior of cell increasing in height as I remove one cell

Comment: Thankfully I managed to find an answer, I will update my question with the solution tomorrow. It was a very simple mistake - in SizeforItemAt I was returning an height base on the collectionViewframe (collectionView.frame/3)and I have changed to a fixed number . Thank you!!!

Comment: @LucaSfragara so your original code worked at the end of the solution I posted ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski shouldn't it be `if (!self.bounds.size.equalTo(self.intrinsicContentSize)) {` (if not equal)?

Comment: @Arjan lol you are right - not sure how it was missed in original answer :D thanks for pointing it out