# Can't scroll with collection view inside scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have the following structure:

```
- Scroll view
    - UIView
        - Collection view
```

I gave the `UIView` the following constraints:

1. top, left, right, and bottom = 0
2. Equal width and height to the `Scroll view`

I've also disabled scrolling for the `Collection view`, as I want the whole page to scroll together.

However, when items are added (dynamically) to the collection view and I try to scroll, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure that the page scrolls all together?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try removing the equal heights between view and scroll view because this limits view's height and doesn't allow collection view to grow.

Comment: If I do that, I get the following error on the scroll view: `Need constraints for: Y position or height`

Comment: The constraints in my question are the only constraints I have

Comment: I just remember that collection doesn't grows dynamically to content height, i recommend you this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437966/how-to-adjust-height-of-uicollectionview-to-be-the-height-of-the-content-size-of)